# Define pay-what-you-want products

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, product, configuration

How can make the customer pick the price of a product?

Is it possible to define price steps for this? Like 5€, 10€, 15€, 20€

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the price of the product to 0 and add custom options with the different prices.

Comment: This is a pretty creative solution

Comment: Why hack a module, if magento does it already? :-)